# Can a Live Tile's count be increase passed 99?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, live-tile

I am starting to use local live tiles ala mango and notice that if I give a count of higher than 99 it cuts it to 99. Is there a way to increase this count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the max count is 99, you can add a string with a number of any size to the back of the tile however.